# How to get the 'alias' of a select

Tags: php, laravel, database

I have two selects:

```
select id,
       name,
       email,
       email_verified_at as email_verified_at
    from users
        where email_verified_at is not null
```

```
select id,
       name,
       active
    from user_groups;
```

And I want to get their alias dynamically through some function in PHP, python, sql...

Some idea?

I try using a function using php and Laravel:

```
function getSelectKeys (string $sql, $connection): array
{
    $records = DB::connection("$connection")
        ->select("$sql");

    if (isset($records[0])) {
        $keys = array_keys(get_object_vars($records[0]));
    } else {
        $keys = [];
    }

    return $keys;
}
```

But it only works when there is some return. If the select doesn't return anything, I can't get the alias even if they are explicit

Comment: `DB::connection(...)->select(...)` will return an empty Array `[]` if no results are returned, and `isset($records[0])` will be `false`, so `$keys` will be `[]`. Unless a result is returned, you won't be able to get the columns or aliases defined in your select statement. Also, `"$connection"` and `"$sql"` are redundant, just do `$connection` and `$sql` (with no `""`).

Comment: Redundant aliases are useless. `email_verified_at as email_verified_at`.

Comment: So let me understand... You have access to the `$sql`, but you want to parse it and get all of the column names/aliases even if the query returns no results?  What if you truncate the query after the WHERE and append LIMIT 1?  `$firstRecord = DB::connection($connection)->select(preg_replace('/ WHERE .*/i', '') . ' LIMIT 1');`  Honestly, though, regex is not an SQL parser.

Comment: Because you aren't using `DB::raw()` inside of `select()`, I would have assumed that you were passing in an array of columns. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions What is your `$sql` string?  Can you just `$records->getQuery()->wheres = [];` then append `->limit(1)`, then execute the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little cumbersome, but you can do this via a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo <your SQL here>;
```

Then you can do

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM foo;
```

This will return you a list of columns, whether or not your SQL produced any rows.

The result can then be retrieved from the temporary table (`SELECT * from foo`) or you can simply drop the table.

Comment: I try this:

select attname
    from pg_attribute
        where attrelid=(select oid from pg_class where relname='foo')
          and attstattarget = -1

Cause I use postgresql, but you SQL resolve my problem. Tanks!